# GroupBy from two tables

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a `GroupBy` statement that I would like to add to. I have two tables that I am pulling from like so:

MU_Reports Table

```
Date      | Shift | Machine | MU
1/12/2016 |   1   |   12    | 44%
1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | 34%
1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | 34%
1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | 54%
1/12/2016 |   3   |   13    | 24%
```

DownTime_Reports Table

```
Date      | Shift | Machine | DT Code  |  DT_Hours
1/12/2016 |   1   |   12    | No Work  |    3
1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | No Resin |    2
1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | No Op.   |    4
1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | No Work  |    1
1/12/2016 |   3   |   13    | No Work  |    5
1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | No Work  |    5
```

Example output:

```
Date      | Shift | Machine | MU   |  No_Work_Hours
1/12/2016 |   1   |   12    | 44%  |     3
1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | 68%  |     0 
1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | 54%  |     6
1/12/2016 |   3   |   13    | 24%  |     5
```

my current `GroupBy` statement adds all No Work together in one shift (no matter date or machine):

```
using (var db = new ProductionContext())
{
   var query2 = from b in db.MU_Reports
                join downtime in db.Downtime_Reports on b.Shift equals downtime.Shift
                where downtime.Downtime_Code.Equals("R09185")
                group downtime by new { b.Date, b.Shift, b.Machine_Number, b.MU } into g
                select new
                {
                      Date = g.Key.Date,
                      Shift = g.Key.Shift,
                      Machine = g.Key.Machine_Number,
                      MU = g.Key.MU,
                      No_Work_Hours = g.Sum(x => x.Total_DownTime)
                };
   query2.ToList();
}
```

As you can see in my example output what I want to do is to add all the No Work in the specific date, shift, and machine at the same time. So in other words I have to look through the Down_Time table to get the correct date then look through those dates to get the right shift then to get the correct machine to then get the right DT reason to get the amount of hours.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228678/looking-up-through-multiple-points-of-similarity/38229877#38229877