# Looking up through multiple points of similarity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `GroupBy` statement that I would like to add to. I have two tables that I am pulling from like so:

MU_Reports Table

```
Date      | Shift | Machine | MU
1/12/2016 |   1   |   12    | 44%
1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | 34%
1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | 34%
1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | 54%
1/12/2016 |   3   |   13    | 24%
```

DownTime_Reports Table

```
Date      | Shift | Machine | DT Code  |  DT_Hours
1/12/2016 |   1   |   12    | No Work  |    3
1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | No Resin |    2
1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | No Op.   |    4
1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | No Work  |    1
1/12/2016 |   3   |   13    | No Work  |    5
1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | No Work  |    5
```

Example output:

```
Date      | Shift | Machine | MU   |  No_Work_Hours
1/12/2016 |   1   |   12    | 44%  |     3
1/12/2016 |   2   |   12    | 68%  |     0 
1/12/2016 |   3   |   12    | 54%  |     6
1/12/2016 |   3   |   13    | 24%  |     5
```

my current `GroupBy` statement adds all No Work together in one shift (no matter date or machine):

```
using (var db = new ProductionContext())
{
    var query2 = from b in db.MU_Reports
                 join downtime in db.Downtime_Reports on new { b.Shift, b.Date, b.Machine_Number } equals new { downtime.Shift, downtime.Date, downtime.Machine_Number }
                 where downtime.DT_Code.Equals("No Work")
                 group downtime by new { b.Date, b.Shift, b.Machine, b.MU } into g
                 select new
                 {
                       Date = g.Key.Date,
                       Shift = g.Key.Shift,
                       Machine = g.Key.Machine,
                       MU = g.Key.MU,
                       NWTotal = g.Sum(x => x.No_Work_Hours)
                 };
}
```

As you can see in my example output what I want to do is to add all the No Work in the specific date, shift, and machine at the same time. So in other words I have to look through the Down_Time table to get the correct date then look through those dates to get the right shift then to get the correct machine to then get the right DT reason to get the amount of hours.

**EDIT:** I updated the code because I attempted to do multiple joins, however, now I do not output anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to produce the desired output. All they require to first group the `MU_Reports` table by `Date`, `Shift` and `Machine`. Then you can for instance do [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_1) the grouped subquery to the `DownTime_Reports` table by `Date`, `Shift` and `Machine` and perform the aggregates:

```
var query =
    from rg in db.MU_Reports.GroupBy(r => new { r.Date, r.Shift, r.Machine })
    join dt in db.Downtime_Reports
    on new { rg.Key.Date, rg.Key.Shift, rg.Key.Machine }
    equals new { dt.Date, dt.Shift, dt.Machine }
    into dtGroup
    select new
    {
        rg.Key.Date, rg.Key.Shift, rg.Key.Machine,
        MU = rg.Sum(r => r.MU),
        NWTotal = dtGroup.Where(dt => dt.DT_Code == "No Work").Sum(dt => dt.DT_Hours)
    };
```